# Weird figure in front of terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this but halfway through doing exercise 15 from Learning Python the Hard Way, I encountered this in my terminal:

162:LPTHW username$

Does anyone know why there's the number 162 in front of that line?
This persists even after restarting my terminal.

Im very new at this, is it a cause for worry?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no need to worry. In a comment, you said your `PS1` (which defines the prompt) was `\h:\W \u\$`. In [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Printing-a-Prompt.html), the meanings of each of those escapes is defined. The thing you're worried about is before the colon. The escape before the colon is `\h`. Here's what the documentation has to say about that:

> `\h`
>   　　The hostname, up to the first `.'.

It's just part of your computer's name. Nothing to be worried about. If you're curious about your entire hostname, try running `hostname`.